# How to join strokes points / closes the figure using grease pencil

Tags: grease-pencil

Is it possible to join two grease pencil stroke points to continue and complete the figure ? (something like E and F between vertices) ?. I created a short video to show you what happens when I try to do it. Thanks.

https://sendvid.com/xk5nfttx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can join Grease Pencil points by selecting two points and hitting CTRL+J, does it work for you?
If I want to do something but don't know whether such feature exists, I often use Spacebar and write down a term that could describe it... in this case I just wrote "Join" and this function with the shortcut appeared in the list.

Comment: Why do you ask the OP if it worked for him? Does it work for you? It doesn't work for me. Ctrl-J does nothing to bridge two vertices that have been selected from within the same grease pencil object. What it does is combine two separate Object-level entities into one Object-level entity. The OP is asking how to bridge a gap between points within a single entity. Hence the reference to "complete the figure", "E" and "F".